# How to avoid horizontal wrapping in CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK ?

Tags: xamarin, cartodb

I want to avoid horizontal wrapping in CARTO Xamarin Mobile SDK.
"Avoid horizontal wrapping" means something like OpenLayers 3's wrapX = false.

Are there any attributes or functions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found it by myself.

```
MapView.Options.SeamlessPanning = false;
```

You can find this here:
http://cartodb.github.io/mobile-android-samples/com/carto/components/Options.html#setSeamlessPanning-boolean-